# Is there an issue with my bisectional search?

Tags: python-3.x

The given problem: use bisectional search to find the minimum monthly payment to pay off debt after 12 payments (slight.
Assume that the interest is compounded monthly according to the balance at the end of the month (after the payment for that month is made).

```
annualInterestRate=.2
balance=320000
monthlyInterestrate=annualInterestRate/12
balance_initial=balance
lowerbound=(1/12)*balance
upperbound=balance*(1+monthlyInterestrate)**(12)/12
monthlyPayment=(upperbound+lowerbound)/2
while balance>-.00001 and balance<.00001:
    for i in range(12):
        balance=balance-monthlyPayment + (balance-monthlyPayment)*monthlyInterestrate
        if balance>0:
                lowerbound=monthlyPayment
        if balance<0:
                upperbound=monthlyPayment
print('Lowest Payment: ' + str(round(monthlyPayment, 2)))
```

With the numbers I provided (.2 annualInterestRate and 32000 balance, the answer should be "Lowest Payment: 29157.09"

The output I am getting is 29591.88

I have been staring at my screen for at least an hour and I am completely lost as to why my answer differs from theirs.

Comment: I think you may find https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to be more suited to your needs.

Comment: I've shoved those numbers through three different calculators and gotten 29643.04 all three times.